# Vertical Scroll with sticky footer extends beyond page

Tags: css, scroll, footer, sticky

Why is it that theres a vertical scroll and the footer extends beyond the page?

Website: www.stingrayimages.ca

Comment: Looks okay to me, but I'm on a 800px high laptop.

Answer (score 0):

Looks okay to me but I am using a 1024x768 monitor.
Try removing `height':100%` and `min-height:100%` etc from the style.css from div#container and it's children. Perhaps this may work.